# How can I remove the CRLF in Given String to resolve issue?

Tags: javascript, newline

How can I remove the **CRLF** in Given String to resolve issue?

As all of us know that Javascript is not support multiple line String.
e.g.

```
var str = "Hello
I am Ashwin";
```

It is Not allowed.
But we should write like this.

```
var str = "Hello" + " I am Ashwin";
```

Or
var str = "Hello \
I am Ashwin";

```
data.setValue(27,       2,  'This is my line with break here
');
```

In above Javascript I have error at Runtime "**SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**"
I want to prepare the data dynemic with replacing the existing CRLF in given string to it will become like this.

```
data.setValue(27,       2,  'Team Effectiveness in Primary Care Networks in Alberta');
```

Thanks In Advance for Great Javascript Solution

Answer (score 0):

The only one way at the moment is yo add *\* at the end of the row:

```
data.setValue(27,       2,  'This is my line with break here\
');
```

Comment: Correct, but sometime data will be come from AJAX Response. So, How can I replace the things at Run-time

Comment: It doesn't matter if it came from AJAX unless you're `eval`ing it (and if you are, stop that, right now).

Comment: When the data comes from an Ajax you will not have this problem.